# Only my last link in my nav bar works , the rest don't even change on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list with a set of anchor links but only the last `li` seems to function as a link in the navbar. The rest don't even change on hover and aren't clickable.

Below is my HTML and associated CSS. Please help thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cross Dominion Ministries</title>
  <link href="homestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="new logo.png">
      </div>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1>Welcome to Church!</h1>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Directions</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-one">About Us</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Programs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but it is something general you should do.  If you do not have a like in an a element, use an href of "#" instead of "".

Comment: You seem to be missing your css.

Comment: The issue must be in the css, because this html results in clickable links. Please include the css and try again